# How to extract parameter and values from a string using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract a param and the value for that param from a string `((created_date{[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z TO *]}|1))`. Here param is created_date. Value is `1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z TO *` where `*` denotes no restriction. I need to extract the data as shown below i,e it should be an array of string.

```
created_date
1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z
*
1
```

I have tried some online regex tool to find a suitable regex and also tried some code on trial and error basis.

```
String str = "((created_date{[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z TO *]}|1))";
String patt = "\\((.*)\\{(.*)\\}\\|(1|0)\\)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patt);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
MatchResult result = m.toMatchResult();
System.out.println(result.group(1));
```

similary `result.group(2)` and `3`.. depending on the `result.groupCount()`.

I need to extract the data as shown below i,e it should be an array of string.

```
created_date

1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z

*

1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
String str = "((created_date{[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z TO *]}|1))";
String patt = "\\(\\(([^{]+)\\{\\[([^ ]+) TO ([^]]+)]}\\|([01])\\)\\)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patt);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
    System.out.println(m.group(4));
}
```

Try it [here](https://ideone.com/I2FnUz) !

Note that you need to invoke a `Matcher`'s `find()`, `matches()` or more rarely `lookingAt()` before you can use most of its other methods, including the `toMatchResult()` you were trying to use.